# custom toolbox controls vb,net

Tags: vb.net, calendar, controls, toolbox

I've downloaded a custom calendar control from here :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378900/Calendar-NET

I added the .DLL file into the toolbox via the "Choose items" link on the toolbox window. Everything works fine. When I then add the object to my form I am faced with 3 errors:

1. Type 'Calendar.NET.Calendar' is not defined
2. 'NET is not a member of 'A2_Coursework_Program'
3. Error 1 again, but on a different line

They all occur with in the designer file. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you downloaded and unzipped the binaries file containing the binaries did you 'unblock' the Calendar.Net.dll prior to importing it into your toolbox.  Have just downloaded and installed into a Winforms application without issue , so I suspect that you haven't unblocked it.

So to correct the issue, delete the control from your toolbox, right click on the dll in file explorer.  Select properties and then click unblock. Now reimport the control into your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I've unblocked the .DLL from the binaries folder. However, I reimported it back into the toolbox, dragged it onto the form and the same errors occur. Could it be that I am missing some other files?